# How to access a class in another project at runtime

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a project (called ExtensibleApp). I'm trying to make it modular. The modules will be dependent on some common classes already in ExtensibleApp.

Say I have a module myModule, that extends ExtensibleApp, and is dependent on a Class `CommonClass.class`, how can I go about importing `CommonClass.class` into myModule project, and get access to the members.

```
class MyModuleClass {
    CommonClass commonClass = new CommonClass();

    private void someMethod() {
        commonClass.method....()
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a project that is extensible via modules. These modules will be loaded/ downloaded into a folder outside the ExtensibleApp classpath. At run time how can I go about linking the two Jars together so that they can share classes.

Sample directory structure:

```
main dir/---ExtensibleApp.jar
        /---plugins ---/myModule.jar
                       /chat.jar
                       /videoplayer.jar
                       /like.jar
                       /unlike.jar
                       /etc.jar
                       /etc_etc.jar
```

Comment: I only know how to accomplish this task using an IDE...are you using an IDE?

Comment: I'd suggest looking into maven or gradle to manage dependencies.

Comment: @Scott Scooter Weidenkopf I'm using NetBeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many frameworks available to achieve this. Following is the list  of some of these

- Maven
- OSGi, if you want finer access control between modules.
- Ant
- Apache Ivy
- Gradle

I've used Maven, OSGi and Ant on eclipse IDE. Out of these I found Maven the easiest and OSGi most useful.